# fetch(:key, nil) vs fetch(:key) { nil }. Which is more efficient?

Tags: ruby

I once been told to use `fetch(:key) { nil }` instead of `fetch(:key, nil)` because even `nil` takes some memory and it's better to evaluate it only if key is not found.

I am not sure if this is right approach. Doesn't this block take some memory too? Is there a way to check this?

Comment: There are several `fetch` methods. Please make clear which class you are referring to.

Comment: Unless your hash has a default value, you can simply use `hsh[:key]`.

Comment: @Stefan there are several advantages of using `fetch` instead of `[]`

Comment: @P.Boro what are the advantages of using `hsh.fetch(:key, nil)` instead of `hsh[:key]`?

Comment: @Stefan e.g. when we expect key to be always present. We can catch errors earlier in the stack and make it easier to debug this way. Google the topic - there are planty of resources .

Comment: @P.Boro `hsh.fetch(:key, nil)` doesn't raise an error if `:key` is missing, it just returns `nil`.

Comment: @Stefan Ah, you are totally right :) But I prefer to always use `Hash#fetch`. Imo `Hash#[]` is often too abused and used even when we require some values to be present. `fetch(:key, nil)` is more verbose. It tells other devs that we do it intentionally. But this is my personal opinion, I just like it this way and that's why I'm asking this question :)

Comment: @Stefan I also use Hash#fetch over Hash#[] for exactly same reasons. It says what keys are required in hash and for me its better to get key not found then undefined method on nil down the road. Also fetch(:key, nil) explicitly says that there might be nil and developer should play around that

Comment: There's only one nil in memory. With `hash.fetch(:key) { nil }` there's now a block that returns nil in the memory too.

Comment: By the way, I never understood these "Which is more efficient" questions. If someone wants to know which one of two pieces of code is more efficient, you just run both and see … which one is more efficient. Which is much more efficient than crafting a question on [so], and then waiting for others to do exactly the same thing you could have done yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000_000

def benchmark(hsh)
  Benchmark.bm(23) do |x|
    x.report('hsh[:key]') { N.times { hsh[:key] } }
    x.report('hsh.fetch(:key, nil)') { N.times { hsh.fetch(:key, nil ) } }
    x.report('hsh.fetch(:key) { nil }') { N.times { hsh.fetch(:key) { nil } } }
  end
end

puts
puts ' Missing key '.center(69, '-')
benchmark({})

puts
puts ' Existing key '.center(69, '-')
benchmark({ key: 1 })
```

Output:

```
---------------------------- Missing key ----------------------------
                              user     system      total        real
hsh[:key]                 0.067592   0.000116   0.067708 (  0.067754)
hsh.fetch(:key, nil)      0.075391   0.000078   0.075469 (  0.075515)
hsh.fetch(:key) { nil }   0.132427   0.000238   0.132665 (  0.132850)

--------------------------- Existing key ----------------------------
                              user     system      total        real
hsh[:key]                 0.058410   0.000007   0.058417 (  0.058422)
hsh.fetch(:key, nil)      0.072805   0.000007   0.072812 (  0.072816)
hsh.fetch(:key) { nil }   0.076052   0.000326   0.076378 (  0.076835)
```

Comment: Great man, that's what I needed! Thank you! :) So `fetch` with block is slower for missing keys. Gonna send your answer to person who told me to use blocks with nil :P

Comment: specify ruby version please

Comment: @MartinZinovsky `ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Answer (score 5):

That's some micro optimization you shouldn't worry about. The difference is more semantic. If the `:key` is not found,

```
fetch(:key, nil)
```

will return the value `nil`.

```
fetch(:key) {nil}
```

will evaluate the block and return the value, although `nil` would be the return value anyway if you use `hash[:key]`

For such a trivial case, I'd recommend using `fetch(:key, nil)`.

Passing a block would enable you to compute a more complex value if and only if the `:key` is not found, e.g.:

```
fetch(:key) { read(url).parse.get('value') }
```

If you really want to know which one is more efficient, you may try benchmarking it, although if the block call is not optimized, I'm quite sure the block will be a bit slower.

Comment: `although nil would be the return value anyway if the :key is not found.` Nope. If there is no value for the key you get `KeyError`. Thats main difference between [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) and `Hash#[]`